# What is the metric of the Riemann surface resulting from quotiening the upper half plane by a Fuchsian group?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the upper half plane, and $\Gamma < SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ be a Fuchsian group. What is the metric we get on $\mathbb{H} / \Gamma$?

Comment: Well, what is your guess?  Why are you having trouble transforming that guess into an argument?

Comment: My guess is that it locally looks like the metric distance on the original space $\mathbb{H}$. Copying how we do it for the torus, it would look like $$d_{\mathbb{H} / \Gamma}(\Gamma x, \Gamma y) = \min_{g_1, g_2 \in \Gamma} d_\mathbb{H}(g_1 x, g_2 y).$$

I do differential geometry by ear, so I am ignorant whether my guess is right or wrong. ;)

Comment: A better way to think about this is by noticing the Riemannian structure of the metric on $\mathbb{H}$.  It comes from a smoothly varying inner product on the tangent space. This inner product is invariant under the action of $\Gamma$ and thus the Riemannian structure descends to the quotient.

Comment: Your guess as to the formula for $d_{\mathbb{H}/\Gamma}(\Gamma x, \Gamma y)$ is correct.